# Error in semantic vocabulary configuration: There are multiple vocabularies with the same prefix 's'

Tags: 2013, dxa, dxa-1.2

We just did a content port to one of our server and published the **Publish Settings** page. Once it got published we started getting  error

> Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException:
>   Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.el.ELException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

on web pages. 
From the logs we noticed that there is an extra prefix 's' added in the `vocabularies.json`
Details:

```
Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.LocalizationFactoryException: Error in semantic vocabulary configuration: There are multiple vocabularies with the same prefix 's'.
               at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.semantics.SemanticsConverter.convertSemantics(SemanticsConverter.java:49) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.2.jar:1.2]
               at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.createLocalization(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:98) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.2.jar:1.2]
               at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.TridionLocalizationResolver.createLocalization(TridionLocalizationResolver.java:88) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.2.02.jar:1.2]
               ... 44 common frames omitted
16:27:47.219 [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'Shared/ServerError'; model is {}
```

We are using DXA 1.2, What could be the reason of getting this error, kindly Suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vocabularies defined in `vocabularies.json` are obtained from global Application Data.
I'm not sure how you ended up with multiple vocabularies with prefix `s` but you can use Bart's custom page to edit this.

See: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-7EA7470E-1592-4734-B824-8F23FF3BD526

Comment: I initially used a link to DXA 1.2 docs (since you mentioned you use that ancient version), but unfortunately that had an outdated link to the custom page. Now linking to latest DXA doc (1.7 at the time of writing)